# Microdata schema person does not show google snippets

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I would like to create an about me page, and make it showing snippets on google search results, for example like Linkedin does (I mean the lightgray string with the location, job, etc about the profile person)

[image]

I tried to create some pages using the schema "person", but the pages do not show the snippets... I used the example schema person code from their website: https://schema.org/Person#eg-1 (microdata), changed only little things like name etc:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
    <img src="janedoe.jpg" itemprop="image" alt="Photo of Jane Joe" />
    <span itemprop="jobTitle">Professor</span>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">
      20341 Whitworth Institute
      405 N. Whitworth
    </span>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Seattle</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">WA</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">98052</span>
    </div>
    <span itemprop="telephone">(425) 123-4567</span>
    <a href="mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu" itemprop="email">
    jane-doe@xyz.edu</a> Jane's home page:
    <a href="http://www.janedoe.com" itemprop="url">janedoe.com</a> Graduate students:
    <a href="http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html" itemprop="colleague">
    Alice Jones</a>
    <a href="http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html" itemprop="colleague">
    Bob Smith</a>
</div>
```

But they don't show any lightgray string...

Theoretically if I copy the source code of some page that is showing those rich snippets, I should be able to have the snippets also on my page: but I think that if I also do that, having the exactly same code, on my website they will not work, and maybe there is something else that I don't know?

Answer (score 2):

Google Search does not provide Rich Snippets for persons (according to [their  documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/)).

Their Rich Snippets for reviewed [Products](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products), authored [Recipes](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/recipes), and authored [Reviews/Ratings](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews) may reference a `Person` though.

(And even if Google Search would support a Person Rich Snippet, note that Google never *guarantees* displaying a Rich Snippet for your results.)

Comment: Yes they do, as I mentioned in my question, LinkedIn shows rich snippets for persons! Look the red area in my image

Comment: @neoDev: I’d guess that this is not a Rich Snippet. Neither does Google list such a Rich Snippet in their documentation, nor does LinkedIn use Schema.org on that page. And the line that Google shows seems to be directly taken from the LinkedIn page’s sub-heading/header (what is written below the person’s name).

Answer (score 1):

Did you test your page with Google's [Structured data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)?

Did you check when Google indexed this page last in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)? Did you check if there were any structured data errors showing in Google Webmaster Tools?

Note that it may take several weeks from the time Google indexes a page with structured data before they actually start showing it on search results. Also Google doesn't guarantee that any structured data they find on your site will ever be shown in search results.

Comment: Yes they seem to work on the testing tool, but not on real google results... At this point, I wonder: maybe they are shown only by certain kind of searches? :/

Comment: How long have you waited for Google to show your rich data? It usually takes several weeks for it to show up. Also, Google probably scans LinkedIn as a social media site, which they treat differently than a standard website.